# Constructor on type not found

Tags: c#, constructor, constructor-exception

Exception Message: `Constructor on type StateLog not found`.

I have the following code that does not work for only one class:

```
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        string line;
        string[] lines;

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURL).GetResponse();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines = line.Split(splitParams);
                list.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), lines));
            }
        }
```

The constructor for the class that it does not work for is exactly like the other classes for which it works. The only difference is that this class will be passed 16 arguments instead of 2-5. The constructor looks as such:

```
    public StateLog(string[] line)
    {
        try
        {
            SessionID = long.Parse(line[0]);
            AgentNumber = int.Parse(line[1]);
            StateIndex = int.Parse(line[5]);
            ....
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException anex)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

Like I said, it works for the other 5 classes that use this, the only difference is the number of inputs.

Comment: On a more serious note, perhaps you should invest some time in telling us how it doesn't work. Error messages?

Comment: Is `StateLog` class visible from that scope? Does it have additional constructor overloads?

Comment: I figured having the error message for the question title would be enough to extrapolate the issue. Will update.

Comment: The line that it happens on would make this a far better question. Relying on the caller to ensure that the array has the correct length, and contains items that are parseable to the correct types in the right positions in that array makes for error prone code. There's generic and there's dangerous. This approach is dangerous. I guarantee that by tomorrow, or perhaps the next day, you'll have forgotten how this works. Anyone else coming to this code will be lost. IMO, passing arrays as parameters is pretty dangerous.

Comment: your constructor does not accept 16 parameters, but only one, of type string[].

Comment: Related post - [How to avoid error “Constructor on type 'MyType' not found” when inheriting a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16325992/465053).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That's because you are using the [`Activator.CreateInstance` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts an object array, which is supposed to contain a list of constructor parameters. In other words, it's trying to find a `StateLog` constructor overload which has 16 parameters, instead of one. This compiles due to [array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx).

So when the compiler sees this expression:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), lines)
```

since `lines` is a `string[]`, it presumes you want to rely on covariance to have it cast it to `object[]` automatically, meaning that the compiler actually sees it like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), (object[])lines)
```

The method will then try to find a constructor which has a number of parameters equal to `lines.Length`, all of type `string`.

For example, if you have these constructors:

```
class StateLog
{
      public StateLog(string[] line) { ... }
      public StateLog(string a, string b, string c) { ... }
}
```

Calling `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StateLog), new string[] { "a", "b", "c" })` will call the second constructor (the one with three parameters), instead of the first one.

What you actually want is to pass the **entire `lines` array as the first array item**, effectively:

```
var parameters = new object[1];
parameters[0] = lines;
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters)
```

Of course, you can simply use an inline array initializer:

```
list.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { lines }));
```

Comment: Then how does it work for my other classes which accept `string[]` as the constructor parameter?

Comment: Do these classes have different ctor overloads which accept more parameters? There is not much to it, the method simply looks for a matching constructor (where number of parameters and their types must match).

Comment: Yes, but so does this one.

Comment: It has an overload which accepts 16 `string` parameters? :)

Comment: No. Neither do the other 5 classes. They all have constructors that accept the parameters in the final type in addition to the `string[]` overload one.

Comment: Try listing them if you want, just the signatures. All constructors for all classes. You should see that the classes where the assignment succeeds have constructor overloads with the exact number of parameters as the length of the `lines` array in that case (and they're all `string`s).

Comment: I get what you are saying now. Its number of parameters that matters. I probably would have gotten that sooner had I more then 3 hrs sleep.

Comment: I had also faced the same type of issue. I changed the access specifier of the constructor from internal to public and then the issue gets resolved.

Comment: Watch out for the type not being an array.  If you are using Linq for instance make sure you convert .ToArray()

Comment: One interesting thing, ran into this - an optional parameter missing in my constructor being omitted in the CreateInstance. 

Fixed it with: Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[2] { lines, null }));